# Angular - How to set property in directive to false from a unit test?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular-directive

I've got this unit test for a directive:

```
it('should not give a height if isActive is set to false', () => {

  debugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(WindowHeightDirective)).nativeElement;

  directive.isActive = false;

  fixture.detectChanges();

  const spy = spyOn(directive, 'setHeight');

  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));

  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(debugElement.style.height).toBe(null);
});
```

It should simply set a property of the `directive` to `false`, which in turn cancels out the setting of a height on the host element of the directive.

However, this does not seem to work. When I log `isActive` inside the directive it's never set to `false`.

I'm picking up the directive instance via the test component I'm using, using `@ViewChild(MyDirective) myDirective: MyDirective`. This gives me the directive instance as expected.

Why isn't this working as it should be?

**EDIT:**

**`unit-test.component.html`**:

```
<div windowHeight></div>
```

**`unit-test.component.ts`**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'unit-test-component',
  templateUrl: './unit-test.component.html'
})

export class UnitTestComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(WindowHeightDirective) windowHeight: WindowHeightDirective;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**`window-height.directive.spec.ts`**:

```
describe('WindowHeightDirective', () => {

  let component: UnitTestComponent;
  let directive: WindowHeightDirective;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UnitTestComponent>;
  let debugElement: HTMLDivElement;

  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        UnitTestComponent,
        WindowHeightDirective
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        {provide: ComponentFixtureAutoDetect, useValue: true}
      ]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UnitTestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    directive = component.windowHeight;
  });

  it('should not give a height if isActive is set to false', () => {

    debugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(WindowHeightDirective)).nativeElement;

    // Doesn't set it to false :(
    directive.isActive = false;

    fixture.detectChanges();

    const spy = spyOn(directive, 'setHeight');

    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(debugElement.style.height).toBe(null);
  });

  ... more tests ...
});
```

**`window-height.directive.ts`**:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[windowHeight]'
})

export class WindowHeightDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() isActive = true;
  @Input() offset = 0;

  @HostBinding('style.height.px')
  height: number;

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  setHeight() {
    console.log(this.isActive)
    this.height = this.isActive ? (window.innerHeight - this.offset) : undefined;
  }

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setHeight();
  }
}
```

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the error. There are far too many unknowns in the code you posted.

Comment: @JBNizet Of course, my bad. I've given a complete overview of everything that's used.

Comment: OK. Not sure exactly what you expect, but here's what happens: the default value of isActive is true, and setHeight is called in ngOnInit. So the height is being set. Then you set isActive to false, **spy on setHeight**, and dispatch an event. So the **fake setHeight method** is called, doing nothing, and thus leaving the height as it is. Don't spy, or use `spyOn(directive, 'setHeight').and.callThrough();` to make sure the real setHeight() method is called.

Comment: @JBNizet What I expect is the `isActive` property to change to `false`. But it doesn't.

Comment: @JBNizet But.. with that said using `.and.callThrough()` does seem to work. Still don't understand why you need to use that though in order for the property change to take effect?

Comment: Because when you spy on a method, you're essentially replacing the method by a fake one that does nothing except recording if it has been called or not, with which arguments, etc. `and.callThrough()` tells this spy method to also call the real spied method.